# How do i make something scroll like this?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I really like the effect on this website http://hydn.co/#hayden

the way that the right side scrolls. I am working on a project and would like to do something like this

how would i achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried this far? It's commonly expected that questions in StackOverflow show some effort in terms of actual code. So, maybe try some programming on your own, and then ask specific questions concerning parts you have trouble with. Consider putting aside a few minutes to take a look at [some guidelines about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) too.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @SamiLaine mark to close as offtopic, downvotes doesn't fix this kind of questions.

Comment: Point taken, thanks.

Comment: container as big as viewport. 2 columns inside container. second column has sections. each section as big as column. columns have `overflow:hidden`. use jQuery to bind scroll event to a function that moves view to next section. ??? profit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the exact plugin they are using on the site you linked,
they use this one: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Answer (score 0):

This is called parallax scrolling.
There's lots of plugins out there, just browse a little bit: [jquery parallax plugins](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-parallax-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

The site appears blank to me, but anyway, if I'm right by what I saw with the url's changes, the entire site is just one page ?

If is this, basically you use the anchors # to achieve determined point whenever you want. In this case probably the designer delected some point of the view to scroll down to the next anchor when the user achieves some point of the site.

This can be set through jQuery, here's a good one [Scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/)